# How can I activate Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome, nvidia

I previously had ubuntu 10.10 installed and upgraded to 11.04. However, desktop is same 10.10 (gnome) as despite the upgrade. How can I disable the Gnome and activate Unity instead?

Comment: I've been giving 11.04 a test run this evening. I was pleasantly surprised to see that it's just good old GNOME that I've come to know and love!

Comment: Unity won't run if you don't have the right drivers, you might need to run 'additional drivers', then reboot and choose "ubuntu" from the log in screen.

Comment: @Jorge Castro i clicked additional drivers, but nothing happened. there is no a window or another thing.

Comment: what is your graphics card? - type lspci | grep VGA in a terminal

Comment: @fossfredoom NVIDIA GT 240M CUDA 1 GB

Comment: burak - Thats OK  - you should be able to activate the NVIDIA driver is Additional Drivers.  However I'm worried about your comment "there is no window...".  Reboot, login into ubuntu classic.  Then open a terminal and type jockey-gtk  ... Edit your question with any errors that you see.

Comment: @fossfreedom i tried but there is no difference, how can i install nvidia?

Comment: Burak - you've marked this thread as answered... but with the wrong answer!  This will confuse people.  Please either unmark the answer or flag it for the moderator's attention.  I've added the "install nvidia driver" as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to activate the NVIDIA Driver in the Additional Drivers Window available when you login as Ubuntu Classic and navigate to System > Administrator > Additional Drivers

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unity is a plugin for Compiz Fusion. It works well with Gnome, actually I don't think it works with anything rather than Gnome (someone might want to follow up on this).

To enable Unity, you have to enable the plugin in your Compiz settings. I'd suggest an app called CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) -- a visual interface to Compiz settings. You can get it from the Software Center. Find Unity in the list and enable the plugin.

**Update**: What if the plugin is already enabled?

Okay what I'm gonna suggest is dangerous, but worked for me. Remember the command `ccsm`,  you might have to use that from the terminal to launch the manager again. Create a shortcut to your gnome terminal on your desktop (`gnome-terminal`). Go to the Compiz settings, go to Preferences and reset everything to defaults.

You might experience some display problems at this point, if your desktop gets unresponsive press `Ctrl+Alt+1`, login and type `sudo service gdm restart`, you might end up with a bare desktop without a single menu (I did). Run the terminal, run `ccsm` and enable the Unity plugin, it'll ask you about some conflicts, ask Compiz to resolve them and disable all plugins conflicting with Unity.

Worked for me at least. Let me know how it goes ;) and good luck!

Comment: i installed CompizConfig Settings Manager, and Unity is active(have tick). but the result is still same.

Comment: @burak I edited my answer to include a sort of hack I used to get this running, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @kovshenin i tried all, but it is not still working.

Comment: @burak, sorry then, I'm out of ideas ;)

Comment: @kovshenin when i restart, there is no unity 2d(i saw on internet). there are Recovery console, Ubuntu, Ubuntu classic, Ubuntu classic(no effect), Ubuntu(safe mode), User definition session. maybe the problem is here

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing any available drivers, check your software sources and make sure that the main, universe, multiverse and restricted repos are enabled.

Then, if you are comfortable in the terminal:

- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings`

If you are more comfortable with synaptic/software center, you can open either one and search for the nvidia drivers, then install them (the packages name are nvidia-current and nvidia-settings).

Answer (score -2):

Log out and then you will see the GDM, click on the drop down menu and select Ubuntu Unity

Comment: There is no Ubuntu unity.There are Recovery console, Ubuntu, Ubuntu classic, Ubuntu classic(no effect), Ubuntu(safe mode), User definition session. I selected Ubuntu.