# Unity desktop does not load, it switches to classic mode

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I activate Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37651/how-can-i-activate-unity)

Ubuntu 11.04 Unity desktop is not loading, instead it switches to "classic" mode. Is this something related to nVidia hardware? By the way, my card is a GeForce 210. Should I try to install the proprietary nVidia drivers?

Answer (score 1):

You must install Nvidia driver if you want to use unity.Install appropriate driver form Hardware Drivers.After reboot unity will be loaded.

**Edit**

If you have Nvidia card and you cannot see any drivers for your card, you can use this PPA to install them right away. (this PPA works on 11.04 also) -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-current-modaliases nvidia-settings
```

and restart the system.

*Source: http://www.linoob.com/2011/04/installing-ubuntu-11-04-and-testing-unity/*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go to additional hardware and try using Nvidia  current Drivers 
Have you tried to log out and see on the bottom of the login screen see if you have ubuntu classic as your desktop 
or you could try this CTRl ALT ESC brings you to tty type in sudo apt-get nvidia current i hope these suggestions help