# Unity doesn't load anymore

Tags: 11.04, unity, gdm

I installed 11.04 a few days ago and the first few boots unity loaded as expected.
But now its just booting into GDM.

I did get one popup about it not being supported on my machine (After the it had booted fine 2 or 3 times!) but i dismissed it without reading it.

I've looked at [How can I activate Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37651/how-can-i-activate-unity) but nothing shows up in my additional drivers except for a wireless chip

the dropdown at login has `ubuntu`, `ubuntu classic` and `ubuntu classic safe mode` i think

Comment: Try removeing any graphics drivers you have and installing them again

Comment: What happens when you select "Ubuntu" and login?

Comment: @Uri how do i remove them? there is nothing in additional drivers
@Roland i get gdm

Comment: sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-* if you have nvidia graphics, sudo apt-get remove fglrx if you have amd/ati graphics

Comment: @Uri purging them worked a treat, haven't re-installed but still seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any Drivers that may be causing the issue:

```
  sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-* if you have nvidia graphics, 
  sudo apt-get remove fglrx if you have amd/ati graphics
```

to get any of them back:

If your system architecture is 64bit (x86_64), you need the ia32-libs package as well.

```
  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

then for both 32 and 64bit:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

and for ATI

```
  wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-4-x86.x86_64.run
```

Once dowloaded right-click the .run file and set it to run as executable.

```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

that will remove the opensource radeonHD driver.

Now this is only if it's a 64bit system:

```
  cd/path_of_the_file       

  sh ati-driver-installer-11-3-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty

  sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb

  sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

For the 32bit system just run the ati installer.

Comment: actually i've just had two nasty crashes of unity/gdm in the past 15mins, i'm guessing its related.. how do i reinstall those drivers? I've tried nvidia-{173,96}-modaliases and nvidia-{96,173} and i get the error ` nvidia-173 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-10
              Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.0-0ubuntu1~) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-96 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-8.0 but it is not installable
             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.8.99.905-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
`

Comment: ... theres my problem ... its not nvidia

Comment: added more info. to know which hardware you have to open a terminal and type hardinfo, install it if you don't have it already.