# I don't see Unity on 11.04 with Nvidia GeForce GT420 graphics card

Tags: 11.04, unity, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I activate Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37651/how-can-i-activate-unity)

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04. But unfortunately cool features those I liked isn't there. I mean Launcher, DashBoard, Workspaces don't showing. How enable them? I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, almost newbie.

Acer laptop, CPU i5, Ram 4Gb, GeForce GT420.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you install the nvidia drivers in the additional drivers?

[image]

It should prompt you to install them, in the panel you should see a little icon.

If it doesn't they can be found `System` → `Administration` → `Additional Drivers`, then go ahead and activate the appropriate driver (probably the `current version`).

After that you will need to restart your computer when prompted and Unity should work.

Comment: How shameful :) It seems didn't installed my Graphic Card driver. After your advice, I installed driver and restarted. At last Magic Happened :) Tnx. Seems like Ubuntu looks cool.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't install by default...

Answer (score 1):

You may install unity-2d-default-settings and try it again.