# Computer does not have the necessary hardware to run Unity

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I activate Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37651/how-can-i-activate-unity)
>   [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)

just downloaded the latest ubuntu 11.04 i think. When i log in it says my computer doesnt have the right hardware to run unity so it just logs me into the old one. I have a hp elitebook 8440p and am running it alongside windows 7. Please help!

Comment: see also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity

Answer (score 0):

It's sound like an issue with the installation recognizing the video card.  I looked around and found [this posted, different computer but same video card](http://bntix.cafelancer.com/2011-05-21/dual-boot-ubuntu-11-natty-narwhal-win-7.html) from Người Điên Lang Thang on the cafelancer.com blog:

> Step 1: Download driver from NVIDIA
>   website :
>   http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index5.aspx?lang=en-us
>   (Linux 64bit for my Dell)
>
> Step 2: Disable nouveau on Ubuntu
>   (open source driver for NVIDIA Graphic
>   Card)
>
> ```
> Press Ctr_Alt_T to open the shell command. sudo su – to gain a root
> ```
>
> permission (nice trick :D )
>       Edit GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable on /etc/default/grub by
>   nano/vi or whatever editor you have.
>   Replace by :
>       GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modeset=0
>   acpi_sleep=nonvs"
>       Save the file and Run “sudo update-grub”
>       Reboot your PC/lappy
>
> Step 3: Install driver from NVIDIA:
>
> ```
> After boot, your Ubuntu looks ugly now he he he he. Don’t worry! It’s
> ```
>
> normal. Press Ctr_Alt_F1 to switch to
>   first text terminal.
>       Login by your account and sudo su – to get root permission
>       Run this command to stop the Graphic Interface service:
>   /etc/init.d/gdm stop
>       Chmod +x for driver from NVIDIA and Run. In my case: 
>   /home/bntix/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-270.41.06.run
>       Follow the instruction, then start the Graphic Interface service by :
>   /etc/init.d/gdm start
>       Then you will get back to a very nice Graphic Interface as before ;-)