# Unity stop working after disk (or drive) error

Tags: unity, boot, gnome

Unity worked perfectly in my laptop before. However, today when I hard rebooted my laptop, there's something like disk/drive error detect before the login screen. I waited until the disk/drive check finished and then login. Now there's a pop up saying: "It seems that you do not have the hardware required to run Unity. Please choose Ubuntu Classic at the login screen ...", then Unity did not work anymore. It turned back to Ubuntu Classic automatically, and I could not use any effect.

Any idea about what happened? How can I get it back? It happened the same before, and it turned into worse after that and I have to re-install Ubuntu. That's why I'm so desperate. Please help.

lspci | grep VGA returns:

> Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller.

Comment: Can you try this and then edit your question with the results? http://askubuntu.com/questions/37651/how-can-i-activate-unity

Comment: It doesn't have any NVIDIA driver in the driver list. lspci | grep VGA returns: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller. Hope it helps.

Comment: That graphics system might not have the capabilities to run Unity... Intel Mobile graphics are not powerful enough in most cases to run the 3D Unity

Comment: So why it worked perfectly before? I did not face any issues until this thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1779234&page=2
For some reasons, my ubuntu installed nvidia by itself. Unity works after I removed nvidia. Thanks for your help guys.